# find the lines with atleast twice repeated pattern?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a big lines with lines as below

```
abc|Abc_12 cdf_rhtdm cdf|Cdf22 abc|Abc_100 ijm|smthr12
ddf|rtg_2 qwe_werth ddf|Cs2 abc|Abc_f0 ijm|styhr12 abc|Abc_33 ddf|Cs2 ddf|rtg_2
ddd_hm ddf|Cs2 ght|d_100 abc|Abc_55
cdf_rshtdm sdf|Cdf22 ght|d_100 ijm|smthr12
```

I want to create a new file that have pattern like `abc|`  **at least two times**

So, here the output will be

```
abc|Abc_12 cdf_rhtdm cdf|Cdf22 abc|Abc_100 ijm|smthr12
ddf|rtg_2 qwe_werth ddf|Cs2 abc|Abc_f0 ijm|styhr12 abc|Abc_33 ddf|Cs2 ddf|rtg_2
```

Comment: your second qualifying line has `ddf|` and `abc|` both repeated. Does it qualify on the basis of `ddf|` or `abc|'?

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep -P` (PCRE):

```
grep -P '(abc\|.*?){2}' file

abc|Abc_12 cdf_rhtdm cdf|Cdf22 abc|Abc_100 ijm|smthr12
ddf|rtg_2 qwe_werth ddf|Cs2 abc|Abc_f0 ijm|styhr12 abc|Abc_33 ddf|Cs2 ddf|rtg_2
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is using `grep` with a basic regex:

```
grep '^.*\(abc|\).*\(abc|\).*$' your_file 
abc|Abc_12 cdf_rhtdm cdf|Cdf22 abc|Abc_100 ijm|smthr12
ddf|rtg_2 qwe_werth ddf|Cs2 abc|Abc_f0 ijm|styhr12 abc|Abc_33 ddf|Cs2 ddf|rtg_2
```

Comment: or less noisily `grep "abc|.*abc|"`

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` it can be done quite simply:

```
$ awk '{if (gsub(/abc\|/, "abc", $0)>= 2) print}' file
abcAbc_12 cdf_rhtdm cdf|Cdf22 abcAbc_100 ijm|smthr12
ddf|rtg_2 qwe_werth ddf|Cs2 abcAbc_f0 ijm|styhr12 abcAbc_33 ddf|Cs2 ddf|rtg_2
```

#### Explanation

From [the AWK manual](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html):

> gsub(regexp, replacement, target)
>
> The gsub function returns the number of substitutions made.

So we check its return code and in case it is 2 or more, we print the line.

Answer (score -1):

The following regex should yield the output you are looking for...

```
.*?(abc\|).*?(abc\|).*?
```